# Prevew data via ajax calls before submitting to the database?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, webmethod

The following ajax calls post data to the database via two webmethods called saveEmpData and saveSourceData respectively.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "#btnAdd0", function () { //
                var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person0').length + 1;
                var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person0">' +
                    '<td><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="employeename' + rowCount + '" placeholder="Your name..." class="form-control employeename01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="employeetitle' + rowCount + '" placeholder="Your title..." class="form-control employeetitle01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="employeeemail' + rowCount + '" placeholder="Your email address..." class="form-control employeeemail01" /></td>' +
                    '<td style="width:200px;"><button type="button" id="btnAdd0" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add More</button>' +
                    '<button type="button" id="btnDelete0" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button></td>' +
                    '</tr>';
                $('#maintable0').append(contactdiv); // Adding these controls to Emp table class
            });
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on("click", "#btnAdd1", function () { //
                    var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person1').length + 1;
                    var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person1">' +
                        '<td><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="sourcename' + rowCount + '" placeholder="Name of income source..." class="form-control sourcename01" /></td>' +
                        '<td><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="sourceaddress' + rowCount + '" placeholder="Address of income source..." class="form-control sourceaddress01" /></td>' +
                        '<td><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="sourceincome' + rowCount + '" placeholder="Income..." class="form-control sourceincome01" /></td>' +
                        '<td style="width:200px;"><button type="button" id="btnAdd1" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add More</button>' +
                        '<button type="button" id="btnDelete1" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button></td>' +
                        '</tr>';
                    $('#maintable1').append(contactdiv); // Adding these controls to Source table class
                });
                     $(document).on("click", ".deleteContact", function () {
                                $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // closest used to remove the respective 'tr' in which I have my controls
                            });
                            function getAllEmpData() {
                                var data = [];
                                $('tr.data-contact-person0').each(function () {
                                    var ename = $(this).find('.employeename01').val();
                                    var etitle = $(this).find('.employeetitle01').val();
                                    var email = $(this).find('.employeeemail01').val();
                                    var alldata = {
                                        'emplName': ename,
                                        'emplTitle': etitle,
                                        'empMail': email
                                    }
                                    data.push(alldata);
                                });
                                console.log(data);
                                return data;
                            }
                            function getAllSourcepData() {
                                var data = [];
                                $('tr.data-contact-person1').each(function () {
                                    var sname = $(this).find('.sourcename01').val();
                                    var saddress = $(this).find('.sourceaddress01').val();
                                    var sincome = $(this).find('.sourceincome01').val();
                                    var alldata = {
                                        'mySource': sname,
                                        'mySAddress': saddress,
                                        'mySIncome': sincome
                                    }
                                    data.push(alldata);
                                });
                                console.log(data);
                                return data;
                            }
                            $("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                                var empComplete = false, sourceComplete = false;
                                function checkComplete() {
                                    if (empComplete && sourceComplete) {
                                        $("#result").text("All complete");
                                    }
                                }
                                $("#result").text("");
                                var data = JSON.stringify(getAllEmpData());
                                console.log(data);
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'testpost.php/saveEmpData',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
                                    success: function () {
                                        empComplete = true;
                                        checkComplete();
                                    },
                                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                                    }
                                });
                                var data = JSON.stringify(getAllSourcepData());
                                console.log(data);
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'testpost.php/saveSourceDatsa',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
                                    success: function () {
                                        sourceComplete = true;
                                        checkComplete();
                                    },
                                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                                    }
                                });

                            });
                       });
                    </script>
            </head>
<body>
   <div class="bs-example">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Dynamic Forms</h2>
            <table style="width:55%" id="maintable0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Employee Name</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="data-contact-person0">
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" style="width:200px;" id="employeeename" name="employeename" class="form-control employeename01" placeholder="Your name..."></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="employeetitle" class="form-control employeetitle01" placeholder="Your title..."></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="employeeemail" class="form-control employeeemail01" placeholder="Your email address..."></td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table><br><br>
            <table style="width:73%" id="maintable1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Income</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="data-contact-person1">
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="sourcename" class="form-control sourcename01" placeholder="Name of income source..."></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="sourceaddress" class="form-control sourceaddress01" placeholder="Address of income source..."></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="sourceincome" class="form-control sourceincome01" placeholder="Income..."></td>
                        <td style="width:200px;">
                            <button type="button" id="btnAdd1" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add More</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table><br><br>
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md pull-center btn-sm" value="Submit">
            <output id="result"></output>
            <br><br><br>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
    <script>
        var x = 1;
    </script>
</body></html>
```

The code above works great thanks to some useful pointers I have gotten from experts of SO.

However, we have a requirement to preview the data first before posting to the database.

I have done this before using webforms and multiview controls but never with ajax calls and webmethods.

Is this possible?

Any pointers is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can  show the data in an alert and then call the ajax.

Comment: @ILikeToMoveItMoveIt, any ideas how to do it with the code I posted?